# Problema em criar tabela no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-html, create

Estou tentando criar uma tabela no `MYSQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE `narguile`.`Aluguel` ( `idAluguel` INT(255) NOT NULL , `produto` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `qntdeProduto` INT(255) NOT NULL , `desconto` DOUBLE(255) NOT NULL , `descricao` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `valordoAluguel` DOUBLE(255) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Mas esta me apresentando o seguinte erro:

> 1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a ') NOT NULL , `descricao` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `valordoAluguel` DOUBLE(255) NO' na linha 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para os campos DOUBLE não é preciso definir o tamanho como no campo VARCHAR(255) que é seu tamanho máximo de caracteres, se for preciso usar acima de 255 caracteres use o tipo TEXT.
Outro ponto importante é que o campo INT tem o tamanho máximo de (10) por se tratar de um número inteiro ele representa o valor entre  -2147483648 e 2147483647. Por exempo, se voce define INT(3) o valor máximo inteiro que ele irá atingir é 999.

```
CREATE TABLE `narguile`.`Aluguel` (
`idAluguel`      INT                NOT NULL,
`produto`        VARCHAR(255)       NOT NULL,
`qntdeProduto`   INT                NOT NULL,
`desconto`       DOUBLE             NOT NULL,
`descricao`      VARCHAR(255)       NOT NULL,
`valordoAluguel` DOUBLE             NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

Não se define tamanho para campos do tipo `double`:

```
CREATE TABLE `narguile`.`Aluguel` (
    `idAluguel` INT(255) NOT NULL,
    `produto` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `qntdeProduto` INT(255) NOT NULL,
    `desconto` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    `descricao` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `valordoAluguel` DOUBLE NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```